# Modelling a hierarchy with record inheritance in a database

Tags: mysql, database, inheritance, hierarchy, rdbms

I am building a database for a system holding lists containing items. A list can contain other lists which, in order to model in the database just requires a list to have a parent column with a foreign key to the ID. However, another requirement of the system is that a list can inherit particular columns from its ancestors, this seems much harder to model.

So, a list might have an ID, title, description and one or more items. However, descendant lists with a null description will inherit description from the nearest ancestor with a non-null value.

I am stumped as to how to model this both in the design and query side. I'm keen for the DB (MySQL) to do the heavy lifting if possible rather than having to do it in code.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You can try nested sets model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive SQL statements so with a basic parent / child relationship you cannot just select all the parents in a single statement. This leaves using a a procedure to perform multiple selects to get the details for your select, or (as suggested above by @user4035 ) using the nested set model. The nested set model works well, but on a database with lots of inserts and deletes being performed it is unwieldy (inserts and deletes are slow), plus it requires changes to your database structure.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm going with nested sets as my application is not write heavy and they seem a very elegant solution.